# Create search/filter for picker

Tags: xamarin.forms

I got a `Picker` which is binded to `viewmode`'s

```
public ObservableCollection<IdValueReadModel> AllClients { get; set; }
```

**Picker:**

```
<Picker Title="Clients"
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding AllClients}"
                        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedClient, Mode=TwoWay}"
                        ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Value}"
                        SelectedIndex="{Binding Id}"
                        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
```

Problem is there are around `400 clients` and my customer requested to have something like `search box` so he could type something and based on that `picker's value` will be choosen (if found/or filtered) according to what he typed. How may i solve that, should i create additional control e.g `Entry`, if so how to construct it to make it along with `Picker`?

Comment: Kinda like `public string EntryString {get; set;} = "";`, and `AllClients = new ObservableCollection<IdValueReadModel>(CallCustomerRequest(EntryString)); //if return a list` ?

Comment: You cannot use a Picker, you have a create a custom modal or separate screen which will have a search box and list item.

Answer (score 0):

I used **Entry's TextChanged method** to realize the worthy filtering of Picker.

Here is the cs code:

```
public ObservableCollection<IdValueReadModel> AllClients { get; set; }
    public MainPage()
    {
        AllClients = new ObservableCollection<IdValueReadModel>();//Data input
        AllClients.Add(new IdValueReadModel("aaa"));
        AllClients.Add(new IdValueReadModel("zzz"));
        AllClients.Add(new IdValueReadModel("zxx"));
        InitializeComponent();
        test.ItemsSource = AllClients;
    }

    private void Entry_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        string res = (sender as Entry).Text;
        ObservableCollection<IdValueReadModel> list = new ObservableCollection<IdValueReadModel>();
        if (res == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        foreach (IdValueReadModel AllClient in AllClients)//Filter value
        {
            if(AllClient.Value.Contains(res))
            {
                list.Add(AllClient);
            }
        }
        test.ItemsSource = list;
    }
```

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: instead of creating new list can it be somehow managed by filter to existing collection? Like using linq where?

Comment: The most important thing is that you need to have a place to store all the data. If you do not create a new collection, when you enter in the entry, the total data will change. Therefore, the total data will decrease with your input. So I will create a new collection to prevent this from happening. If you use SQLite, you can also avoid this problem.

Comment: xu Li i solved that issue by triggering an event from Entry control and from xaml.cs code behing i call it like this: private async void InputView_OnTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)        {await_viewModel.LoadSearchedClientCommandAsync.ExecuteAsync(e.NewTextValue); } then in viewmodel i better make Clear() against Observablecollection rather than creating new instance as from my experience sometimes it led to other issues in MVVM and then afterwards i call api to get data and based on NewTextValue .

Comment: Yes, if you have an API to get data, you don't need to create a new collection. I wrote dead data for demonstration purposes.Mainly provide achievable methods.